# Obtaining part of an expression from a position

Tags: expression-manipulation

I would like to recover a subexpression from its position in the expression.

For instance:

```
 Position[{3, {3, 5, {6}}}, 6]
```

returns the position of 6 in the list, namely:

```
 {{2, 3, 1}}
```

to recover the list element 6 from the position {{2,3,1}} we can use;

```
 {3, {3, 5, {6}}}[[2]][[3]][[1]]
```

which returns

```
 6
```

However, I want to apply {3, {3, 5, {6}}} in one go, rather than repeatedly applying it, first to [[2]], then to [[3]] and finally to [[1]].

It seems that I need something close to FoldList which would apply expr[[#]] & repeatedly to elements of list consisting of the flattened position, where the position indicates a subexpression in expr.

I am not sure if this plan is workable.

It seems such a natural operation to recover a subexpression based on its position. Is there a Mathematica defined function for this?

Comment: That's precisely what `Extract` is made for.

Comment: you can also do: `{3, {3, 5, {6}}}[[##]] & @@@ Position[{3, {3, 5, {6}}}, 6]`

Comment: Thanks both, that works. I'd like to select reply 1 by Henrik as the answer and learned from kglr's observation. Forgot you could access matters also as: {3, {3, 5, {6}}}[[2, 3, 1]] rather than {3, {3, 5, {6}}}[[2]][[3]][[1]]

Comment: See also [`Position`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Position.html), "Details and Options," second bullet point.

Comment: Thanks, It would be nice if the documentation had Extract as part of the examples too. Extract is a natural complement to Position. It is buried a little in Details and Options, appearing as one of three in one sentence. I will keep that section in mind for future reference.

Comment: Look at the first example under "Properties and Relations," which is a natural place to look to see how the function being looked up (`Position`) relates to other functions.

Comment: Thanks, that's clear indeed.

Comment: You're welcome.